# Simple enquiry on hash algorithm

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, sha

After reading the article from the link listed below :

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=910203

I am trying right now to prove and understand why the hash listed below is insecure and should not be practice by programmer.

H(k || m) --> SHA1("secret-key" + "name=bob,withdraw=$200")

H(m || k) --> SHA1("name=bob,withdraw=$200" + "secret-key")

As per stated by the article, The first example is totally, fatally broken. SHA1 (and MD5 and many other hashes) are machines that share a common design called Merkle-Damgaard, which means that they process messages in block-length chunks, and use those blocks to permute an internal state. The output SHA1 is the "final" contents of that state. But there's nothing that actually "finalizes" the SHA1 state; if you see the SHA1 value on the wire, you can keep cranking the Merkle-Damgaard machine with **additional data**. **That means you can mint new messages with arbitrary data tacked to the end that will appear to be authentic**. This attack is incredibly easy to carry out; it takes ~20 lines of Ruby code.

The second example is also broken, and it's the subject of this blog post. If you tack the key on after the message, you can't keep driving the hash with data, because a secret you can't guess goes on the end of it.

I have wrote a simple hash function in C# trying to prove what the author claim but somehow i cannot seem to do it no matter what i add/pad or behind/infront of the message.

```
        string strRet;
        // hash contains the SHA 1 value of SHA1 (key + temp)
        string hash = "ce0037fbbff7a1b68b5794bd73dcc7d63338f115";

        try
        {
            string key = "password";
            string temp = "name=bob,withdraw=$200";

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp);
                SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
                strRet = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");
                strRet = strRet.ToLower();
                MessageBox.Show(strRet);

                if (strRet.Equals(hash))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Hash are equal !");
                    MessageBox.Show(temp);
                }

                temp = key + temp + "2";
            }

            MessageBox.Show("The End !");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is a Error !");
        }
```

Can someone guide me on this by providing a specified example that i can hash, understand and prove what the author claim in the article for both of the hash method. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Re: "I have wrote a simple hash function in C# trying to prove what the author claim but somehow i cannot seem to do it no matter what i add/pad or behind/infront of the message"  -- explain to us in simple terms precisely what you believe the author is claiming.  You are probably unable to prove what the author is claiming because you do not correctly understand the claim. Your code doesn't appear to have anything whatsoever to do with the claim made.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am actually using the algorithms and after reading this article i am thinking of using HMAC as it is stated right now the 2 algorithm i am using is insecure ? Hence i have wrote a simple c sharp code listed above. From what i understand is that without knowing the key the attacker can somehow get authenticated which is what i am trying to prove. To summarise i am trying to understand and prove why using the 2 methods is insecure ?

Comment: From Wiki Due to the block and iterative structure of the algorithms and the absence of additional final steps, all SHA functions are vulnerable to length-extension and partial-message collision attacks.[9] These attacks allow an attacker to forge a message, signed only by a keyed hash - SHA(message | | key) or SHA(key | | message) - by extending the message and recalculating the hash without knowing the key. The simplest improvement to prevent these attacks is to hash twice - SHAd(message) = SHA(SHA(0b | | message)) (0b - zero block, length is equal to block size of hash function).Any expln ?

Answer (score 12):

Let's take a step back.  First off, what do we mean by `H(k|m)`? And what is this for?

The goal here is as follows.  Alice and Bob share a secret key. How they share it, we don't know. Somehow Alice and Bob have agreed upon a secret key, and no one else knows it.

Alice wishes to send a message to Bob. Alice does not care if anyone can read the message, but Alice cares very much that Bob knows that Alice wrote the message.

They come up with the following scheme. Alice will create a message that consists of the secret key followed by the rest of the message. She will then hash the whole thing. She then transmits the message without the secret key to Bob, along with the hash.

Bob attempts to verify that the message came from Alice. He puts the secret key in front of the message and hashes it. If Bob gets the same hash out, then Bob knows that whomever made the message possessed the secret key. He knows it wasn't him, so it must have been Alice.

This scheme is not secure. Mallory wishes to send a false message to Bob and trick him into thinking it is from Alice.

One day Alice takes her secret key "123SesameStreet" and a message "Dear Bob, I love you!", and she appends them together to "123SesameStreetDear Bob, I love you!" She hashes that to "398942358092" and sends the hash and the message "Dear Bob, I love you!" to Bob.

Mallory intercepts the message before it gets to Bob. Mallory does not know the secret key, but she does know the message and the hash. Mallory sets up the SHA1 algorithm to have the state 398942358092, and then runs the characters "Just kidding I hate you!", and gets a hash out of 92358023934. Now Mallory sends the new hash and the message "Dear Bob, I love you!Just kidding I hate you!" to Bob.

How precisely does this work? Here's the deal. Basically, SHA1 works like this oversimplified sketch:

```
int hash = 0;
foreach(char c in message)
    hash = MakeNextHash(hash, c);
```

That is, you start with zero. Then you hash the first character and the number 0. Then you hash *that hash* with the *second character*. That makes a new hash.  Then you hash *that* with the third character, to make a third hash. Keep doing that until you run out of characters; the last hash you made is the hash of the whole message.

The real SHA1 algorithm uses blocks larger than a single character and state larger than an int, but basically that's how it goes. It transforms a bunch of state one block at a time, using the previous state as the input for the next state.

So if I tell you "Here's a string M. Also, the string KM has hash H(K|M)." then obviously you can work out the hash H(K|M|Z) of KMZ for any Z, *even if you don't know K*. You just say:

```
int hash = HKM;
foreach(char c in Z)
    hash = MakeNextHash(hash, c);
```

and the result is H(K|M|Z), even though you don't know K.

So, you see how this goes. Bob prepends the secret key to the message and runs it through the SHA1 algorithm, and he gets back the right hash. So he has verified that the message is from Alice, when really half the message is from Mallory.

That's why the key has to go last. You have to put the key *after* the message, not before. You'd think. Turns out that though the attack is now not *trivial* as it is with the key-first scheme, it is still not safe. The `H(m|k)` scheme is also no good.

Why not?

Suppose Mallory has intercepted a message M and a hash H which is H(M|K), where K is the secret key. She prevents the message from arriving.

Mallory computes H(M), easily enough. The hard part is that Mallory deduces a damaging message N such that H(N) = H(M).  How she does that, we do not yet know, but it is widely believed that such a technique exists, we just have not found it yet.

Mallory knows that H(N|K) is the same as H(M|K), by the same reasoning as before -- because to compute H(N|K) we're going to do:

```
int hash = HN;
foreach(char c in key)
    ....
```

to work out H(N|K). Mallory needs not know K in order to make a message N such that H(N|K) is H(M|K).

So now Mallory sends N and H(M|K) / H(N|K) -- they are the same thing -- to Bob. Bob appends K to N, and verifies that the message came from Alice, when in fact it came from Mallory.

It gets worse. Suppose Mallory has captured a million messages M1, M2, ... and a million hashes H(M1|K), H(M2|K), ... that have passed between Alice and Bob. Mallory needs to craft a message N such that H(N) matches *any* of H(M1), H(M2), H(M3), ... Her job just got a million times easier.  She finds such a message N such that H(N) matches, say, H(M1234), and then sends N and H(M1234|K) to Bob. Bob fails to notice that he's seen that hash before, and believes that this is a message from Alice.

It gets worse. Let's change up the scheme a little to see how it gets worse. Carol has a message that she would like to send to Bob via Alice. The message M is "Hey Bob, this is Carol. Let's you and me and Alice all have lunch together next week. If Alice agrees she will send you this message with her authenticator." Carol does not know the secret key K, but Alice does. Alice agrees with the message M, so she computes H(M|K) and sends M and H(M|K) to Bob.

Now Mallory wants to cause trouble, so she searches for two messages B (for benign) and D (for dangerous) such that H(B) is equal to H(D), and such that Alice will agree with B but will not agree with D. This is much easier than searching for a message N which matches a *given* message from Alice because now Mallory gets to choose *both* messages. The job of finding a collision is orders of magnitude easier.

Mallory finds those two messages and sends B to Alice. Alice agrees with the message, computes H(B|K), and sends H(B|K) and B to Bob. Mallory intercepts the message B and replaces it with D. H(B|K) and H(D|K) are the same by the same reasoning as before. Bob receives message D and verifies that H(D|K) matches the hash he was sent, so he knows that Alice approved of the message, even though she did not.

No one has yet found a way to make SHA1 reliably produce collisions like that, but just about everyone believes that we will solve this problem.

The first moral of the story is **do not use either of these techniques as a message verifier**. The first is trivially broken, and the second will likely be broken in our lifetime.

The second moral is **never allow a potential attacker to choose the message that you are going to process with your secret key.**

Comment: Thanks for your input once again. But it is also stated in the article that putting your key after the message can be broken as well. I can understand where you looking at it from. What i have done is when a user try to access my server i will give him certain information based on the cookies stored on his/her PC. My program will create a cookie SHA1(date || A secret password). According to the date i will give him extra info i am wondering how the user can edit the cookie and get extra information. Some of the article that i have looked http://www.vnsecurity.net/t/length-extension-attack/

Comment: Since i have done the following SHA1(date || A secret password). i was wondering how can a user change the cookies to gain additional information from my server. As it is stated in the article that it can be done without knowing the secret password. Which is my actual problem ?

Comment: @ Eric . 1 last question i am curious how can Mallory set up the state of SHA 1 state to 398942358092 and run the character "Just kidding I hate you!", and gets a hash out of 92358023934 ?

Comment: Wait, if `message + key` is easily compromised, what _should_ we use to sign messages?

Comment: @configurator: Just send the message encrypted with your private key? How we share the public key is a separate question, just as with the original question sharing the secret key was a separate question.

Comment: @Brian: But this isn't about private/public key encryption, it's about signing a message with a secure hash...

Comment: @configurator: :::Reads CodeInChaos's Answer::: Then use HMAC.

Comment: @user1012147: I've updated the answer to explain in more detail how the three different attacks work.

Comment: Phew. The update (about it not being broken yet) makes sense now. I have to ask though - if the entire message + key is one block, which in SHA-1's case is 64 bytes (or for SHA-512, 128 bytes), this technique doesn't apply, right?

Comment: Excellent answer. I always thought Mallory was a male name, though.

Comment: @NickJohnson: Mallory is usually a surname. When used as a first name it can be a male name but since the 1980's, when "Mallory Keaton" was a character on the popular sitcom "Family Ties", it has been overwhelmingly a female first name in the United States. When used as the canonical attacker in crypto sketches, Mallory (and Eve and Alice!) is pretty much always characterized as being female.

Comment: @EricLippert I stand corrected. I know I've seen Mallory mentioned in crypto sketches before, but I didn't recall it being used as a female name.

Answer (score 2):

You could have linked http://rdist.root.org/2009/10/29/stop-using-unsafe-keyed-hashes-use-hmac/ which is the source for this claim.

It says that this hashing scheme is weaker than it needs to be, not that it can practically be broken with SHA-1.

This scheme is only vulnerable if the underlying hash functions has any weaknesses (second preimage for the first attack, and collision for the second). From what I remember SHA-1 has no discovered practical vulnerabilities to either of them, whereas MD5 is broken in the context of the second attack.

Since collisions are the easiest vulnerability to discover in hash functions, it is a good idea to use a construction that's not vulnerable to collision attacks unless necessary. That's why the HMAC is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the input. While researching earlier i have already come across that side.

Comment: SHA-1 hasn't been broken yet, but it's getting there.  If you were going to use a hash, SHA-2 would be safer.

Comment: MD5 has issues that allow precisely this kind of attack, and it was used to falsify SSL certificates. Whilst SHA1 is based on the same construction as MD5 (Merkle-Damgaard) which means it may break similarly in future. You should use one of the SHA2 family algorithms, RIPEMD160, or Whirlpool. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities